# VS ASP not returning the correct values from the model

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I can't work this one out - your help please.

I have a simple model:

```
public class Family
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string FamilyName { get; set; }

    public  virtual List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

and set it up with data like so:

```
Family family = new Family
{
    FamilyName = "Smith",
    Children = new List<Child> 
    {
    new Child { Name = "Samantha"},       
    new Child { Name = "Julie"},       
    new Child { Name = "Michael"},       
    new Child { Name = "Terrance"},
    new Child { Name = "Joseph"},       
    }
};
```

I then load this up into a simple ASP.NET form and display the family model. I also have a button to delete the relevant Child from the Family. It submits the index value of the `List<Child>`.

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(btn);
family.Children.Remove(family.Children[i]);
```

However no matter which child I try to delete the form always returns the top four entries.

Let us assume I delete `Michael`. I have traced the object and the correct child is removed from the model and I have traced the model through to the ASP page build and the correct model values are sent to the page-builder. However even though `Michael` is not in the model, it somehow remembers him and returns him as part of the result, always dropping the last one off the end.

```
 Original List                  Returned list
 -------------                  -------------
 Samantha                       Samantha      
 Julie                          Julie
 Michael                        Michael
 Terrance                       Terrance
 Joseph
```

I have tested this in VS-2013, VS-2015 and VS-2017. All versions return the same result.

This seems like a bug in VS or .NET but it seems too elementary to be true. Can anyone pinpoint the problem?

Code at: https://github.com/johnmackerras/wierdVSerror

Comment: could you check the value of "btn" in debugger if it corresponds to the index of the button clicked. i have doubts that because multiple buttons with same name (btn) are contained withing single form and when you submit , it submits only the last value, hence you always receive same last value which removes last entry from your collection.

If my suspicion is correct then you should use a hidden field in your form lets say "ItemToDelete" and using javascript, on click of that button set the value of this hidden field to index of button. then use "ItemToDelete" at server end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

good to put a project that illustrates the issue. Really helps!

Indeed when I run the project it shows the behavior you described.

If you put a break-point on the line where the child is removed from the list, you'll notice that the correct child is indeed removed. But when (re)rendering the page the wrong value is shown. This is because the entered values in the textboxes are saved in the ModelState, and pasted back.

To illustrate:

If you change the `return View(family);` into

```
        ModelState.Clear(); 
        return View(family);
```

you'll see that it will functions as expected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome - would never have got this myself. It feels like it should be a bug if modelState gets out of sync with the actual model, but this would be an EntityFramework bug not a .NET bug.

Comment: It's not really a bug of the ModelState. The values are pasted back by ID of the control. The ID is based on the iterator variable of the for-loop. If you look at the generated HTML you'll see the inputs get ID of `Children_0__Name`, `Children_1__Name`, `Children_2__Name` et cetera. When the child is removed, the matching iterator value should also be removed. So, if you base the control's ID on the actually ID field of the child object, instead of the iterator then it would work as expected.